# Disable /change button text until click procedure complate?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have asp Button  (runat="server") in my web form into update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDoIt" runat="server">
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralDoIt" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <asp:Button ID="ButtonDoIt" runat="server" Text="DoIt"/>     
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this button do something when i click .

```
Private Sub ButtonDoIt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDoIt.Click

   me.ButtonDoIt.Enabled=False
   me.ButtonDoIt.Text="Please wait..."

   bla bla bla bla 'it takse one or two minute
   LiteralDoIt.Text="<a href= bla bla"
   bla bla bla bla

   'finish process

   me.ButtonDoIt.Enabled=true
   me.ButtonDoIt.Text="Process Complete!"

End Sub
```

**But my button not disabled or not change text when click this button**

Only can i see "Process complete" when process finished.

In windows form,i always use "application.doevent" after change buttontext line .and i see changing on my form.

But asp.net not allow this.(i use vb.net)

How can i do?

Thanks a lot for interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Disable Button and Change Text of button</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sc" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
 document.getElementById('<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>').innerText = "Processing...";
 args.get_postBackElement().disabled = true;
 }
 </script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlSubmit" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Add Script Tag in source page . change Id of button in code . You can disable the button till the process completes execution .

Comment: that is exactly what i am wanted.
thanks a lot Brad!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="btnid" value="Save" />
```

**JS**

```
 $(function(){
       $('#btnid').click(function(){
        $(this).val('processing...');
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        setTimeout(function(){$('#btnid').val('finished');$('#btnid').removeAttr('disabled');},5000);
    });
 });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wp87F/1/)**

Comment: thanks but where is my real process code lines at serverside? This example not work for me.

Comment: You tagged `jquery` that is why i did it using `jquery`. i hope you need the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax, or you will need to estimate a time and do as @Kiranramchadran did.

Look the following example using AJAX in VB.NET

**Class Name**

`Public Class NameHere`

**VB Page_Load**

```
Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(GetType(NameHere), Me.Page)
```

**VB Function**

```
<Ajax.AjaxMethod()> _
Public Function ButtonClick() ...
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    // Here you can disable your button

    // Call your ajax function
    NameHere.ButtonClick();
});
```

Comment: @FıratK. NameHere is your Class Name. For example: "Public Class Test" ... Your NameHere = Test
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479042.aspx)